# How to make custom methods in svelte store with parameter?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

I would like to make custom svelte store that can be called like this:

```
$myStore.changeValue("my new value") // this would set new value to writable store
$mystore // this would return current value of the store
```

Is it possible in Svelte?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the built-in [`set` method](https://svelte.dev/docs#writable) if you can.

```
const currentValue = $myStore;
myStore.set('my new value');
```

Note that you only use the `$myStore` syntax when accessing the value, not when calling methods on it. Behind the scenes, this [subscribes to the store](https://svelte.dev/docs#4_Prefix_stores_with_$_to_access_their_values).

If you want to define a new method on a store, you can add it to the exported store. Stores only need to define a `subscribe` method to honor the [store contract](https://svelte.dev/docs#Store_contract).

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

const store = writable('This is a test');

export default {
    subscribe: store.subscribe,
    changeValue: store.set
}
```

This can then be called in your component.

```html
<script>    
    import myStore from './myStore.js';
    
    function handleClick() {
        myStore.changeValue('new value');
    }
</script>

<h1>myStore: {$myStore}!</h1>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Update store
</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this method

```
// store.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    
    export function MyStore(value) {
      const { subscribe, set, update } = writable(value)
    
      return {
        subscribe,
        set,
        update,
        changeValue: function (value) {
          // put your logic here
    
          // call update method to make the store reactive when the value get changed
          update((oldValue) => value)
        },

      }
    }
```

Using the custom store:

```
<script>
   // App.svelte
   import {MyStore} from './store.js'

   const myStore = MyStore("Empty")
</script>

<button on:click={e=> (myStore.changeValue((new Date()).toString()))}>
   Store: {$myStore}
</button>
```